# My first generic casting (C#)

Tags: c#, generics

I was all excited at writing this generic function when the compiler threw an error (`unable to cast T to System.Web.UI.Control`)

I basically pass it a type when I call it, and it look for all controls of that type. The error occurs on `l.Add((T)ctrl);`

```
    private List<T> RecurseTypes<T>(Control ctrls)
    {
        var l = new List<T>();
        foreach (var ctrl in ctrls.Controls)
            if (ctrl.GetType() is T)
                l.Add((T)ctrl);
        return l;
    }
```

Am I missing something or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Where is T coming from. Let me see the class declaration.

Comment: @Jannis: It's not coming from a class, this is a generic *method* : `RecurseTypes<T>`.

Comment: What line throws an exception?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
private List<T> RecurseTypes<T>(Control parent) where T: Control
{
    var l = new List<T>();
    foreach (var child in parent.Controls)
        if (child is T)
            l.Add((T)child);
    return l;
}
```

2 changes:

- add a `where T : Control` generic constraint
- see the `is` usage (the *control* can be a `T`, but `GetType()` returns `Type`, which is *never* a `Control`)

Also, note that this doesn't really recurse; this could just be:

```
return ctrl.Controls.OfType<T>().ToList();
```

Comment: @ssg  - no, I don't think so. It sounds like @maxp is after the *child* controls of a particular type; that doesn't mean that the *parent* control needs to be that. For example, all the `TextBox` controls inside a `Panel`; `T = TextBox`, `ctrl` is a `Panel` (not a `TextBox`).

Comment: @ssg it doesn't have to be. The reason is that the items going into the list are checked for their type the parameter just needs to be a control. It doesn't have to be the same specific type as the T.

Comment: @Ani - sorry, I read the wrong line - you must have been topmost on my page. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or later, you can use the `OfType<T>()` or the `Cast<T>()` extension method instead of writing your own.

`OfType<T>()` will return a subset of the initial collection that were able to be cast, while `Cast<T>()` will return the entire collection cast to the desired type, but will throw an exception if one of the elements in the collection could not be cast.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us more details?

Why not following code:

```
private List<T> RecurseTypes<T>(Control ctrl)
    {
        List<T> l = new List<T>();
        foreach (var ctrls in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrls is T)
                l.Add((T)ctrls);
        }
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: Because that causes a compiler error: Error 1 Cannot convert type 'Foo.Control' to 'T'

Answer (score 0):

Putting a constraint will help you.

```
private List<T> RecurseTypes<T>(Control ctrls) where T : System.Web.UI.Control
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe T isn't the type of desired control.

I mean that you don't ensure that you are casting from Control to T where T is ??? inheriting from Control.

First thing you need is add a generic constraint:

```
private List<T> RecurseTypes<T>(Control ctrls) where T : Control
```

Then, you don't have a clue for knowing if the iterated controls are T. You need to check if it's a subclass of Control:

```
 if (ctrl.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Control))
```

Finally, you can now assume that list of controls will be storing controls of type T.